# Oracle SQL - Suppliers Who Served Products The First Two Days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four related tables "suppliers", "products", "orderdetails", "orders" (I think that relationship should be made)

**-"suppliers" has these columns**

```
SUPPLIERID, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME,
CONTACTTITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION,
 POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX, HOMEPAGE
```

**-"products" has these columns**

```
PRODUCTID, PRODUCTNAME, SUPPLIERID,
 CATEGORYID, QUANTITYPERUNIT, UNITPRICE,
 UNITSINSTOCK, UNITSONORDER, REORDERLEVEL, DISCONTINUED
```

**-"orderdetails" has these columns**

```
ORDERID, PRODUCTID, UNITPRICE,
 QUANTITY, DISCOUNT
```

**-"orders" has these columns**

```
ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, 
TERRITORYID, ORDERDATE, REQUIREDDATE,
 SHIPPEDDATE, SHIPVIA, FREIGHT, SHIPNAME,
 SHIPADDRESS, SHIPCITY, SHIPREGION, SHIPPOSTALCODE,
 SHIPCOUNTRY
```

***I need the names of the suppliers that served products the first two days of June 1997***

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM suppliers 
JOIN products ON suppliers.supplierid=products.supplierid
JOIN orderdetails ON products.productid=orderdetails.productid
JOIN orders ON orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid

where  orderdate between TO_DATE('01/06/97', 'DD/MM/YY')
                    AND TO_DATE('02/06/97', 'DD/MM/YY');
```

Comment: Column orderdate data type?

Comment: What happens if you skip the WHERE clause for a while, and instead add orderdate to the SELECT clause.

Comment: If you use hours / minutes, then you won't get any data for 1997. Otherwise, please specify what "doesn't work" mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are using the format model `YY` which assumes that the date is in the current century so you are looking for dates in `2097` and not `1997`. To fix it you can use the `RR` format model, a 4-digit year or use a date literal `DATE '1997-06-01'`.
2. In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that **ALWAYS** contains 7-bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second; so it will always have a time component. You are searching from `??97-06-01 00:00:00` to `??97-06-02 00:00:00` and you will miss any data on the second day that does not have a midnight time component. You can search on the entire range or you can `TRUNC`ate the time component to midnight.

To fix it you can use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT companyname
FROM   suppliers 
       JOIN products ON suppliers.supplierid=products.supplierid
       JOIN orderdetails ON products.productid=orderdetails.productid
       JOIN orders ON orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid
WHERE  orderdate >= DATE '1997-06-01'
AND    orderdate <  DATE '1997-06-03';
```

or:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT companyname
FROM   suppliers 
       JOIN products ON suppliers.supplierid=products.supplierid
       JOIN orderdetails ON products.productid=orderdetails.productid
       JOIN orders ON orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid
WHERE  TRUNC(orderdate) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/06/97', 'DD/MM/RR')
                            AND TO_DATE('02/06/97', 'DD/MM/RR');
```

*Note: filtering on a date range allows Oracle to use an index on the `orderdate` column; if you use a function, such as `TRUNC` then Oracle will not use an index on the column and would require a separate function-based index.*

Comment: thank you so much for your clear explanation, it helped me a lot to understand what was happening